# Download link for a server side file in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple controller that creates a model with a list of a custom object representing log4net log files.

The path to log folder is `/Logs/`. On the view, I'm getting the full file name. I need to build a  with correct download linkto the file:

[image: Download-Links]

I have tried `<td><a href="@("/Logs/" + file.FileName)" title="@file.FileName" target="_blank">@file.FileName</a></td>` and the prodices `http://localhost/Logs/Finance-Web-2018-03-20.log`

I tried `<td><a href="@("~/Logs/" + file.FileName)" title="@file.FileName" target="_blank">@file.FileName</a></td>` and got `http://localhost/finance-web/Administration/~/Logs/Finance-Web-2018-03-20.log`

Both are wrong. In my case, the link should be `http://localhost/finance-web/Logs/Finance-Web-2018-03-20.log`

`finance-web` is IIS virtual folder

How do I get the correct address?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
@Url.Content("~/Logs/" + file.FileName)
```

Comment: It does generate the correct address yet I still get a 404. I think I'll have to process the file at the server level